# Register and unregister a DLL in a Windows Setup Project

Tags: windows, dll, setup-project

I have couple of dll files that need to be registered/unregistered when a Windows installer is installed/uninstalled respectively.

I tried the following -
 Created a .bat file to register the dll. The issue is I am not able to add a .bat file using 'Custom Actions' in Setup Project.

Also, how to run unregister dll while uninstalling ? Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: What toolchain?  Just about every development tool out there offers a project template called "Setup Project".

Comment: Use the Register property for the DLL.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention - I am using "Setup Project" provided in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below info is my registering DLL steps:

1. Add "*Common Files*" folder.
2. Add your DLL-files into this folder.
3. Modify DLL file's property "Register" to "`*vsdrfCOMSelfReg*"

Now settings done.

After you install your project, you can find *Common Files* folder exists with DLL (like my path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files")

You can find DLL key has been registered in your RegEdit too.

If you uninstall your project, those info will be removed.