# setup project in visual studio 2008 fails to register dll

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vb6, dllregistration

I built an application in VB6, and made a setup project for it using VS2008. It deploys fine on my dev machine, but I get the following error while trying to install it on the client machine.

Module C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\SQLDMO.dll failed to register. HRESULT -2147024714. Contact your support personnel.

I have to re-register SQLDMO.dll to make the application successfully running.

Comment: Not much in the description to work with, but see if the answer in this question helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490524/register-and-unregister-a-dll-in-a-windows-setup-project

Comment: Does it really deploy OK on your dev machine? Or do you already have that DLL registered there?

Comment: I take it you can manually use regsvr32 to register it?  If so, it's not likely a dependency issue.  Are there other dlls/ocx's that are registered or is this the only one? (to eliminate admin rights as the issue)